# Dealing with disconnected users

Tags: game-design, online

Just a strange question. I was thinking about it today. About a poker game website/apps or any online gaming platform with money being involved.

What would be the best way to deals with disconnected users trying to avoid a loss or maybe real disconnection.

I doubt pausing the game until that player comes back is very suitable.

Any ideas? Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Amount they bet stays in the pot and their chips get put back into their account. If they want to re-enter the game then allow them.

Is there more to your problem than what you're asking?

Comment: No, you answered it right. :) Doesn't that change the dynamic of the current game if someone is constantly leaving and entering every round?

Comment: Well, leaving and entering should not give you any advantage, but I cannot see how leaving a poker game, and then reenter would....